# How to optimize this Django query

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-debug-toolbar

I installed `django-debug-toolbar` and am seeing this query getting executed on every page request.

```
QUERY = u'SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."username" IS NULL LIMIT 21' - PARAMS = ()

Connection: default
```

Here is the `INSTALLED_APPS` ins `settings.py` file.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'djcelery',
    'hct',
    'kombu.transport.django',
    'debug_toolbar'
)
```

The time it takes vary from page to page. I have no table called `auth_user` defined in my `models.py` file. From where is the query getting executed and why on every page request. Is there a way to optimize this query?

Comment: Have you tried creating an index on `auth_user.username IS NULL`?

Comment: I do not have this table in models.py, so where should I create the index and since this query gets executed on every page load. Is there a way in django to cache this result

Comment: You should create it directly in the database.

Comment: What are your installed apps? I can't find this query in the main Django package.

Comment: It might be some middleware or a context processor that queries for the current user, which is queried as `'username' IS NULL` for unauthenticated users. I don't know where it came from, but I also wouldn't worry too much about optimizing the query itself. A good caching framework should resolve any performance issues, if it creates any in the first place.

Comment: this might be ``django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware`` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/_modules/django/contrib/auth/middleware/#AuthenticationMiddleware and you dont need to optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

Django issues automatic LIMIT 21 when printing querysets. Could it be possible you are printing this query somewhere for debug purposes?

Answer (score 0):

auth_user is a default table which Django creates when you start a new project. What I would recommend is creating a new project (don't change anything), and using this [database browser tool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/). This will help you better understand what happens when you create a new project.